# I want to access United Kingdom and Germany current time and date by pressing navigation bar items respectively

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <script>
    let a,b;
    let date,date1,date2;
    let time,time1,time2;
    const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
    setInterval(() => {
    a = new Date();
    date = a.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);
    time = a.getHours() + ':' + a.getMinutes() + ':' + a.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time + "<br>on " + date;
    }, 1000);
    setInterval(() => {
    const date1 = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 11, 20, 3, 23, 16, 738));
    time1=a.getHours() + ':' + a.getMinutes() + ':' + a.getSeconds();
    document.getElementByClassName('navbar-nav mr-auto nav-item active 
    nav-link').onclick="time1 + "<br>on "(en-GB) + date1";
    document.getElementById(time2).innerHTML = time1 + "<br>on " +
    date1;
    }, 1000);

    setInterval(() => {
    const date1 = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
    time2=b.getHours() + ':' + b.getMinutes() + ':' + b.getSeconds();
    document.getElementByClassName('navbar-nav mr-auto nav-item active 
    nav-link').onclick="time2 + "<br>on "(('de-DE')) + date2";
    document.getElementById(time2).innerHTML = time2 + "<br>on " +
    date2;
    }, 1000);
   </script>
```

1.point

1)I want to access United Kingdom and Germany current time and date by pressing
navigation bar items respectively.

Comment: I think you'll need an API to get time info for other timezones.

Answer (score 0):

With new date api you can get time for a specific locale:

`console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' }));`

`console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('de-DE', { timeZone: 'UTC' }));`

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString